# What are the differences between "Latest Posts" and "Static Page"?

Tags: wp-query, pages, page-template

WordPress has an option to pick "Latest Posts" and "Static Page" under "Settings" in Admin Panel. My questions:

1. What page template is getting loaded in each of those modes?
2. Why `paged` stops working and `page` starts working when I select "Static Page" - `paged` works, however, when I create new page template with new WP Query and `page` doesn't work (this is about WP Query - I think that everyone knows what I'm talking about - it's pagination).
3. It looks like `get_post_meta($post->ID, "my_custom_field_name", true)` stops working when I select custom page template as "Static Page" but the same thing works when I use it via standard "View Page" in Admin Panel (I haven't tried `global $post`, yet).
4. I think that all my above questions are related to what gets inside `$wp_query` and `$post` in each of those modes.

I just don't get these two options :) Can someone provide me some guidance or resources where I could find out more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Conditional Tags

- The `is_front_page()` Conditional Tag returns `true` if you're on the *Front* Page (`index.php` as fallback or `front-page.php`).
- The `is_home()` Conditional Tag returns `true` if you're on the *Front* Page, when you got *no* static page set as front page, or when you got a static front page and display the *Posts Page* (`home.php` or `index.php` as fallback).
- If you got *no* static front page set under "Settings > Reading", then both `is_front_page()` and `is_home()` will return `true` for `home.php`, `front-page.php` and `index.php`.

### Options

- If you got a static front page, then `get_option( 'show_on_front' );` has the value `page`.
- To retrieve the ID for the *Front* page, you can call `get_page( get_option('page_on_front') )`.
- To retrieve the link to the *Front* page, you can call `get_permalink( get_option('page_on_front') )`.
- To retrieve the ID for the *Posts* page, you can call `get_page( get_option('page_for_posts') )`.
- To retrieve the link to the *Posts* page, you can call `get_permalink( get_option('page_for_posts') )`.
- If you have a child theme, then `home.php` will *not* act as fallback for `front-page.php`.
- To retrieve custom values from the *Front* page, you can call `get_post_custom('page_on_front') )`.
- To retrieve custom values from the *Posts* page, you can call `get_post_custom('page_for_posts') )`.

... the list of *AAARGH!!s* goes on and on.

> especially when user tries to set custom template as "Static Page" - pagination stops working unless I use page and custom fields stop working unless I create new WP Query.

<sup>From a comment of the OP to another answer</sup>

As you can see [in this diagram](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/385), it's not that easy to get around what to use where. The problem is that there're functions that intercept the main `$wp_query` object, others that copy over the contents of the `$wp_the_query` object, etc. And than there're those that only work with the main `$wp_query` object. I know this is no full answer to your pagination question, but this also has never been the question. :)

Comment: Great format for an answer to this question :) It's already very useful. They should have put exactly the same information in WordPress Codex. My main concerns are: `page` vs `paged` and `$wp_query` - what gets inside and custom templates set as "Static Page" behave strangely in various areas.

Comment: Any further news on that? So far I managed to improve my files significantly according to your advice :)

Comment: @Paul Yes, a short one, but please open a new question if you want to ask about other things like for e.g. pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer that question (not enough time left today), I'll just link you some track tickets, that show that the UI, function naming, etc. is highly questioned:

- [Improve the UI](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16379) under "Reading > Settings"
- [Allow non-editable pages to be classified & organized as "System Pages"](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21665)
- [Rename the highly confusing `is_blog()` function and introduce `front_page_url()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18705)

Comment: Thank you! I just started reading. That's really helpful :) I'm using Twenty Eleven theme as reference but indeed I feel like I can come up with better template structure ideas and "Static Page" + "Latest Posts" seem to put some limitations on my ideas - especially when user tries to set custom template as "Static Page" - pagination stops working unless I use `page` and custom fields stop working unless I create new WP Query.

Answer (score 1):

1. you basically select two templates, one for the front page and the other for the blog page. It is kinda hard to understand from your question to which one of them your questions refer...
2. The page template associated with the static page you selected there. The latest posts page will ignore the template setting and will use the templating instructions from home.php or index.php.
3. Because a page content is not paged ;). The latest posts page should be paged, at least on my test installations it works fine.
4. Need to see the exact code, but $post is global, it is better to always declare it as one instead of assuming that your code is not being executed from a function and therefor doesn't have access to the global scope.
5. For the static home page they will contain the same values as if you try loading the page by its own URL. For the latest posts the should contain the same values the would have contained if you were loading the home page before messing with the static page configuration.

Yeh this thing is complicated to understand :( codex can actually help here http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page